# Setting up 1/4 of memory of virtualbox on vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, ubuntu-server

I'm new on vagrant and I'm trying to put my machine to 1/4 of system memory like this:

```
config.vm.define "UbuntuServer2" do |server2|
server2.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
server2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "50"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 'echo -n $($(awk '/MemTotal/' {print $2} /proc/meminfo / 1024 / 4))']

 end
end
```

But i'm getting this error:
   Path: 
   Line number: 38
   Message: NameError: uninitialized constant MemTotal

How I can init this variable?
I'm using MacOs 10.11.5
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I am using in such case if your host OS is mac

```
config.vm.define "UbuntuServer2" do |server2|
  server2.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  server2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "50"]
    mem = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024 / 1024 / 4
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem]

  end
end
```

I got a more complete script that can help anyone if needed

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      host = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
      # Give VM 1/4 system memory & access to all cpu cores on the host
      if host =~ /darwin/
        cpus = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
        # sysctl returns Bytes and we need to convert to MB
        mem = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024 / 1024 / 4
      elsif host =~ /linux/
        cpus = `nproc`.to_i
        # meminfo shows KB and we need to convert to MB
        mem = `grep 'MemTotal' /proc/meminfo | sed -e 's/MemTotal://' -e 's/ kB//'`.to_i / 1024 / 4
      else
        cpus = `wmic cpu get NumberOfCores`.split("\n")[2].to_i
        mem = `wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize`.split("\n")[2].to_i / 1024 /4
      end

      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", cpus]
  end
```

Comment: whats your OS ?

Comment: I'm using MacOs 10.11.5

Comment: ok updated for your OS - the command you had was for linux so I thought you had a linux based host

Comment: Thanks Frederic! Worked fine :)

Comment: Sure! Thanks again :)